# Counting unique strings where there's a single string per line in bash

Tags: bash, count

Given input file

```
z
b
a
f
g
a
b
...
```

I want to output the number of occurrences of each string, for example:

```
z 1
b 2
a 2
f 1
g 1
```

How can this be done in a bash script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [**`sort`**](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/sort/) the input and pass to [**`uniq -c`**](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/uniq/):

```
$ sort input_file | uniq -c
 2 a
 2 b
 1 f
 1 g
 1 z
```

If you want the numbers on the right, use [**`awk`**](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/awk/) to switch them:

```
$ sort input_file | uniq -c | awk '{print $2, $1}'
a 2
b 2
f 1
g 1
z 1
```

Alternatively, do the whole thing in `awk`:

```
$ awk '
{
    ++count[$1]
}
END {
    for (word in count) {
        print word, count[word]
    }
}
' input_file
f 1
g 1
z 1
a 2
b 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat text | sort | uniq -c
```

should do the job

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
awk '{ freq[$1]++; } END{ for( c in freq ) { print c, freq[c] } }' test.txt
```

Where test.txt would be your input file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `bash`-only version (requires bash version 4), using an [associative array](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html).

```
#! /bin/bash

declare -A count
while read val ; do
    count[$val]=$(( ${count[$val]} + 1 ))
done < your_intput_file # change this as needed

for key in ${!count[@]} ; do
    echo $key ${count[$key]}
done
```

Comment: requires bash version 4 for associative arrays

Comment: Simpler: `(( count[$val]++ ))`. Also, you should almost always use `-r` with `read`. Always quote variables: `for key in "${!count[@]}"` and `echo "$key ${count[$key]}"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort filename | uniq -c`.

Have a look at [the Wikipedia page on uniq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniq).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
cat -n file | 
sort -k2,2 | 
uniq -cf1 | 
sort -k2,2n | 
sed 's/^ *\([^ ]*\).*\t\(.*\)/\2 \1/'
```

This output the number of occurrences of each string in the order in which they appear.